# InstaSharp authentication without user interaction

Tags: c#, instagram-api, instasharp

I'm trying to write a service, that can get the Instagram feed for a specific user.

Im using InstaSharp, but I can't figure out how to do the authentication without redirecting the end user to a https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize url

I can't find any examples, beside [this](http://kataribe.naist.jp/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/tree/5c94049f20e579e62b5dc0a26c5dc584f6179755) (and others looking like it)

Can anyone give me any pointers. 
For now I have a Instagram app in sandbox mode, and a selection of users, who have accepted the sandbox invite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with this library. You better generate your access token by yourself - https://elfsight.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-get-instagram-access-token/ and then request user's feed as like this

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{USER-ID}/media/recent/?access_token={YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN}
```

If you want to deserialize your JSON object to c#, please use this service - http://json2csharp.com for generating your class and then using Newtownsoft library:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourClass)
```

Good luck.

Comment: You are right. Getting a app approved to access the API is almost impossible. So we ended up going with access-tokens.

You can use this URL insted: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=

There you only need the access-token, not a user ID